# Eurail is it worth-travel between Lyon and London

Tags: eurail

My son who is studying in Lyon, France wishes to make use of his weekends by travelling to other European cities in the weekend. In addition he intends visiting his sister who is studying in London. To this end he intends getting a Eurail pass.SNCF website makes no difference in price whether you hold a Eurail Pass or not. Is UK not considered as part of Eurail network? I am confused.

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but my daughter found it much cheaper and faster to use low-budget carriers to fly. Partly perhaps because she was studying in Spain without a high-speed train connection, but flights to just about anywhere in Europe were dirt cheap.

Comment: The page for [**Eurail Global Pass**](https://www.raileurope.com/pass/eurail-global-pass-5880) says *Travel on the national rail networks of up to 31 countries - including Great Britain*. This page [How (And Why) to Add London to Your Eurail Trip](https://blog.eurail.com/how-and-why-to-add-london-to-your-eurail-trip/) states *As of 2017, your Eurail Pass is valid on the famous Eurostar high-speed train between London, Lille, Brussels, and Paris.* You might also consider a [Britrail Pass](https://www.britrail.net/passes/britrail-pass) which can be bought only outside UK.

Comment: For traveling to London the Britrail pass is not much use (if any.) Have him check early bought train tickets, those are often way cheaper than a pass. Flights are often also cheaper than a rail pass but do check the price to get to and from the airports.

Comment: Unless he's traveling a great deal, a Eurail pass is likely more expensive than just buying tickets when he wants to go. And as @JonCuster points out, flying is way cheap, and a lot faster.